# ContextThemeWrapper doesn't work for attributes that are defined in styles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

ContextThemeWrapper is great for programmatically setting a new theme for inflating views.

This works fine for something like:

```
<TextView
  android:textColor="?attr/textColorPrimary"
  />
```

But surprisingly doesn't work for:

```
<TextView
  style="@style/Label"
  />
```

```
<style name="Label">
  <item name="android:textColor">?attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

**Is there a way to allow the style to read the correct attribute values from the ContextThemeWrapper used to inflate the view?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply a theme overlay not a style in this case:

```
        <TextView
            android:theme="@style/Label"
            ../>
```